# Gatling recorder 2.0 does not record query params

Tags: gatling

I am currently migrating from 1.5 to 2.0 but it seems gatling recorder 2.0 does not record query parameters. Instead it give me long http get query?

```
.exec(http("request_2")
        .get("""/computers?f=macbook""")
        .headers(headers_0))
```

Do I have to convert this long http get string into a version with query params like this. It does not seem a problem in this example but sometimes get query can be realy long.

```
.exec(http("Search")
  .get("/computers")
  .queryParam("""f""", """macbook"""))
```

In the previous version it can successfully convert the request into queryparams version

Has anyone experience this? I am aware that It can convert post requests with parameters successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both forms are equivalent. We changed for recording as query for conciseness.

Comment: So as far as I understand I can not record with get query params set in Gatling 2.0

Comment: No you can't. But you can edit manually if you really have to. But once again, the generated request will be the same.